# Angular Calling function in service from component

Tags: angular

This is my service,

```
@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) 
export class DashboardService {
    BacklogList: EngBacklog;   
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    }

    getEngBacklog(){
        return this.http.get(environment.apiURL + 'PSP');
    } 
}
```

And this is my component,

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

radioModel: string = 'Month';
EngBacklogList: EngBacklog[];

constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService){} 
ngOnInit(): void {
     this.dashboardService.getEngBacklog().subscribe(
       res => this.EngBacklogList = res as EngBacklog[]);  
}
```

It gives an error saying :
Property 'getEngBacklog' does not exist on type 'DashboardService'

What can be the problem?

Comment: try to restart "ng serve"

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be fine for me, but there maybe two reasons for your issue,

> 1. *Proper import statements*

Check if your **`import statement`** for your `Service` class has done properly.

> 2. *Dependency Injection*

You did not gave your `Service` class in **`Providers array`** in your Module.

Check here more about [Service class usage](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services).

Comment: I don‘t think he needs to put his service in Providers array because he already have @Injectable({ providedIn:root}). Maybe he needs to make his method public?

Comment: by default all methods are public: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing any issues in the code. 'EngBacklog' type already exists. Your method name says 'getEngBacklog()'. Try changing the method name and check whether it helps.

**Service:**

```
getEngBacklogData(){
    return this.http.get(environment.apiURL + 'PSP');
}
```

**Component:**

```
this.dashboardService.getEngBacklogData().subscribe(
    res: EngBacklog[] => this.EngBacklogList = res);  
}
```